# How to add new fields in my registration form

Tags: php, html

I want to add extra fields in my registration form like date of birth, city, country, and marital status. I am new to PHP and PDO.

Here is my code:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields are required.';
    } else {
        if ($users->user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'That username already exists';
        }
        if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter a username with only alphabets and numbers';
        }

        if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6) {
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be atleast 6 characters';
        } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) >18) {
            $errors[] = 'Your password cannot be more than 18 characters long';
        }

        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        } else if ($users->email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'That email already exists.';
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        $users->register($username, $password, $email);
        header('Location: register.php?success');
        exit();
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar" style="box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
            <?php include 'includes/menu.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <!-- NAV BAR DIV closes here -->
        <div id="main-wrap" style="box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
            <div id="container">
                <h1>Register</h1>

                <?php if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) { echo 'Thank you for registering. Please check your email.'; } ?>
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <h4>Username:</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>">

                    <h4>Password:</h4>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                    <h4>Email:</h4>

                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['email']); ?>" />

                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
                <?php if (empty($errors) === false){ echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>'; } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Container DIV closes here -->
        </div>
        <!-- Main Wrap DIV closes here -->
    </body>

</html>
```

How do I add the extra fields?

Comment: give pastebin link  of your code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WtHyns0M        register.php file  asn one more file i have that users.php                                                         http://pastebin.com/Dq5Aicb8    here is users.pph

Comment: Sidenote: You didn't close PHP before going into HTML.

Comment: Fred that not seems full code i tried to paste in question here but couldnt , here is pastebin links for files register.php and users.php http://pastebin.com/Dq5Aicb8          second one is here http://pastebin.com/WtHyns0M

Comment: now i posted links to code and everybody got quite :(

Comment: @EvilP: in general we try not to recommend that people use pasteboards here. JS Fiddle or codepads are fine in order to make it easy to _run_ the code, but otherwise we want questions to be self-contained. This means that if Pastebin drops off the internet, or the paste is deleted, the question will not become useless.

Comment: @Awlad: see above about recommending pasteboards here - we prefer people to paste the code into the question. In general, if the amount of code is excessive, it is likely that the OP needs to narrow the problem down further anyway.

Comment: @halfer: hi, yes you are right :) i also know that. OP was unable to add any code.so i was suggested him to do so.

Comment: @Awlad: thanks. Best approach (imo) is to note the existence of the `[code]` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question. You'll need code to handle adding the input to the database, but that warrants a separate question.

For the PHP, you'll need to decide how to validate each field, and then add another `if` block for each question. For the HTML, you'll need to add another input for each field.

### Example Code

For date of birth, you should probably ensure that it's a valid date. And then you may want to validate age as well.

You might use PHP code like this for birth date:

```
//test date
try {
    $max_date = new DateTime('13 years ago');
    $birth_date = new DateTime($_POST['birth_date']);
    if ($birth_date > $max_date) { {
        $errors[] = 'You must be at least 13 years old.';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = 'Birth date is not a valid date.';
}
```

You could then use the following to format the date for MySQL:

```
$birth_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Relevant PHP manual pages:

- [DateTime::__construct](http://php.net/datetime.construct.php)
- [Relative date/time formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative.php)
- [DateTime::format](http://php.net/datetime.format.php)

And you might use HTML code like this for birth date:

```
<h4>Birth Date:</h4>
<input type="text" name="birth_date" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['birth_date'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['birth_date']); ?>" />
```

You could also format the input into separate fields for each part of the date and use drop down menus. I don't find this is necessary since the `DateTime` class can handle a wide variety of formats. However, I usually add a [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to make it more user friendly.

---

### Other Fields

The above should give you a good starting point. You can do something similar for each field. You need to **show more personal effort** if you expect people here to help.

If you have specific questions about how to validate the other inputs, you should post a separate question (after first searching for the answer). Show what you've tried. Describe the result and explain how it's different from the expected result.

---

### Suggestions for Code Improvement

1. I'd combine the two `if` blocks for username. If the username already exists, you don't need to validate the format.

   ```
   if ($users->user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
       $errors[] = 'That username already exists';
   } else if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) {
       $errors[] = 'Please enter a username with only alphabets and numbers';
   }
   ```
2. Comparing the return value of `empty($errors)` to true or false is redundant. The return value is always a boolean. You only need `if (empty($errors))` or `if (!empty($errors))`.
3. You should use `label` elements in your HTML instead of `h4` elements to make your HTML more semantic. You can then use CSS to style them however you want.

   ```
   <label for="fld-password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" id="fld-password" name="password" />
   ```

Comment: where to paste this code ? in users.php or register.php :(

try {
    $max_date = new DateTime('13 years ago');
    $birth_date = new DateTime($_POST['birth_date']);
    if ($birth_date > $max_date) { {
        $errors[] = 'You must be at least 13 years old.';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = 'Birth date is not a valid date.';
}

Comment: That is the code to validate user input and would go in register.php with the other validation blocks. You'll need additional code in users.php as well to actually insert the new input into the database. Of course, you'll first need to add new tables/columns to store the new data. And then you'd need to edit `$users->register($username, $password, $email);` to pass the new input.

Comment: yes dear i have created field in data system named birth_date (date)
and also created input field in regsiter form, but dont know where to paste that validation code or in which :(, here is link to download files if you can help me please and if you will add something please metion in comments so i will ber able read and understand https://www.dropbox.com/s/w72ibyhasw2zjj5/mysourcecode.zip best regards Andy judge

Comment: As I said, paste in register.php - just look for the other sections with `$errors[] = `. There is a section there already for username, password, and email. This code is a bit different than the other sections, but just think of the `try` like an `if` and the `catch` like an `else`. I would paste it in so that the error messages end up in the same order as the input fields. So if you put the birth date field after email, put this code after `$errors[] = 'That email already exists.'; }`

Comment: @andyjudge85: the author has put a great deal of effort into this answer, so please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.